# How to fetch a movable image background for an activity in android?

Tags: android, background-image, animated-gif

How to place a movable image background (**LIKE LIVE WALL PAPER**) in android for an activity?

For that have i to use the .gif image backgrounds?
If so how?If not why?

Suggestions please..

Thanks for your precious time!...

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#frame-animation).This might be what you are looking for. There is also another [tutorial](http://weavora.com/blog/2012/02/07/android-how-to-use-animated-gif/).Please check